# Scaffold instead of Container

Tags: flutter, dart

Scaffold occupies the available space to it, and sometimes Container can be replaced with Scaffold.

By using Scaffold instead of Container gives any performance issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no performance issue here.
`Scaffold` is used as a root of a screen to get access to setting `Appbar`, `FloatingActionButton`, `BottomNavigationBar`, showing Snackbar, etc.

Whereas a `Container` is just a simple... well a Container where you can define custom shape & constraints.
Also, a `Continer` won't always take up entire space, for that you can either use `Expanded` or a `Spacer` widget.

Scaffold **will** take whole screen space as it is meant to be used as a root of a widget screen.
A `Scaffold` should not be used instead of a `Container` unless you want to explicitly use `Scaffold`'s properties.

Comment: The question is "Can we use Scaffold instead of Container" you said it in reverse.